# C string removal - how does this code work?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have a working piece of C code that completely removes every second char from a character array, making the original array half the size (half+1 if the size was odd)

..but I cannot figure out how it works.

```
void del_str(char string[]) {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0, j=0; string[i]!=0; i++) {
        if(i%2==0) {
            string[j++]=string[i];
        }
    }
    string[j]=0;
}

//
example input: 'abcdefgh'
output from that: 'aceg'
what I thought the output would be: 'aacceegg'
```

The line I don't understand is

```
string[j++]=string[i];
```

I can write code that omits every second char, so the output would be:

```
'a c e g '
```

but I can't wrap my head around this.

Alternatively, how would you write a program that completely deletes every n-th char and their space in the original array? (producing the same output as the above code)

Comment: Pick a language, bro.

Comment: You say that input is **"abcdefgh"** and the output is **"acfg"**, so my question is, shouldn't be the expected output **aceg** ? For my side this is your  **"every second char from a character array"**.

Comment: You are completely right, I edited that part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code uses two position indexes, `i` and `j`. Initially, both indexes are initialized to zero. Index `i` is used for reading; index `j` is used for writing.

Index `i` is incremented at each step of the loop, because the increment `i++` is in the header of the loop. Index `j`, on the other hand, is incremented every other iteration, because `j++` happens only when `i` is even. Index `i` is always as close or closer to the end of the string than index `j`, because it moves "faster".

Null terminator is placed at the final position of `j` at the end of the loop to indicate the new position of string's end.

Perhaps it would be easier to see with a small example. Consider the initial string of `"abcdef"`. Its representation in memory at the beginning of the algorithm is as follows:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' '\0'
```

Here is how it would change after each step of the loop:

```
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' '\0'
'a' 'c' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' '\0'
'a' 'c' 'e' 'd' 'e' 'f' '\0'
'a' 'c' 'e' '\0' 'e' 'f' '\0'
```

Since C strings ignore everything after `'\0'`, the "tail" of `'e' 'f' '\0'` is not considered part of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
The part I was missing was the '\0' being duplicated and finishing the string at half the size.

Answer (score 1):

i and j are not the clearest variable names. Perhaps renamig `j` to something like `output` would help.

Note when `j` is updated, only when you're at an odd position. So `i` is walking through the whole list while `j` brings up the read copying something from `i` back to the `j`th position, overwriting what was there before. The last line, `string[j]=0`, terminates your string.

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the `if(i%2==0)` which is crucial. This line basically skips every second character. Then, the line you have identified can be split in 2 parts:

```
string[j]=string[i]; // Overwrite the character at position j
j++;                 // Now increase j
```

The variable `i` keeps track of the position of the string you have reached while reading it; `j` is used for writing. In the end, you write 0 at position `j` to terminate the string.